# Capture Bar Code as image and Decode it using ZBAR

Tags: zbar

Currently i am using ZBAR reader for decoding the QR codes. It is working fine. The problem occurs when QR code is heavily populated. ZBAR takes some time to read the content and due to this delay, the camera is kept open which annoys some users. **So is there any way to capture the QR code as image and store in local and decode the image of QR code from local**. This will stop the camera immediately and user won't see the camera opened for a long time. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say anything about platform or language, but the the answer is "yes". See [these examples](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Scan_images_using_the_API).

Comment: It is unfortunate the link no longer works.  (It now redirects to the project's main page.)  If a hint of the correct API was provided in the answer, it would still be a useful answer.